# OpenCV: How to get weak lerners from adaboost in

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, adaboost

Is there a way to extract the features corresponding to the weak learners from the adaboost algorithm implemented in Opencv ?

I know that adaboost combines a set of weak learners based on a set of input features.
The same features are measured for each sample in the training set. 
Usually adaboost uses a decision stump and sets a threshold for each feature and chooses the decision stump having the minimum error. I want to find out what are the features that generated the weak learners.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to save the model and extract the trees/stump from the text file.
The [save()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/statistical_models.html#cvstatmodel-save) api is quite simple to use. In the file you will find items like this:

"splits:
                  - { var:448, quality:5.0241161137819290e-002,
                      le:1.7250000000000000e+002 }"

The number next to "var" is the feature index and the "le" is the "less than" value for this feature.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have saved the model and I will try to parse the xml and extract the <var> field.

Comment: I have parsed the xml file and some surprising issues come out.
I have used 500 weak learners - hence I should have 500 features (I supposed they are different).
After parsing I discovered that I got 38 different feature indices and one feature index repeats for 440 times. Is this ok, correct . 
Have you tried to parse the variables in a CVBoost learner ?

Comment: What you see is not a bug. Adaboost reweight each sample after each tree/stump so the same feature can be the best more than once. But having so many times the same feature could mean that you are overtfitting or that your other features are not interesting. Maybe you don't have enough data. As you can see there are many possible reasons and it is your job to evaluate why this feature is so important and why the other ones are not even used.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will analyze my data. Something is wrong in there.

Comment: Do you know any other C/C++ implementations of AdaBoost ? I have used OpenCV but I cannot see any debugging information from it (for example the classification error whenever a weak learner is added to the model).

Comment: Sorry, I'm using EmguCV (C# wrapper on OpenCV) and I have even less debug info than in C/C++ but it's still the best I found. You could try with Weka or R.